# Request error after creating Sanity project

Tags: sanity

everytime I'm creating a Sanity project I get this request error:

```
Error: Request error while attempting to reach https://pa0hlgbk.api.sanity.io/v2021-06-07/users/me?tag=sanity.studio.users.get-current
Error: Request error while attempting to reach https://pa0hlgbk.api.sanity.io/v2021-06-07/users/me?tag=sanity.studio.users.get-current
    at xhr.onerror (http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-5WWDMH23.js?v=21964db0:24757:13)
```

I tried different ways for example with pnpm to create the project, but nothing helped.
Any ideas?